How to prove sequential commands C1; C2 can always execute to C2 if we know C1 always terminates?
I am using a theorem prover to demonstrate the progress of programs.
The semantics of a program are defined using a small-step relation, denoted as
ctran, between program configurations. A program configuration is defined as (C,s) where C is a command and is a state. a valid execution is thus defined as (C1,s), (C1', s') \in ctran. we use ctran* to denote the transitive reflexive closure of ctran. The termination of a program is then defined as exists t, such that (C1, s), (term, t) \in ctran*. Now I already have (C1, s), (term, t) \in ctran*, How can I prove (C1; C2, s), (C2, t) \in ctran*

That depends entirely on the rest of your definitions. What is the definition of ctran? What does it say about when a program where the top-level operator is sequence can step?

That being said, the answer is most likely "by induction on the reflexive transitive closure," at least for Coq. In other words, by taking each step on the given execution and "wrapping" it a larger context.

In course material for semantics of programming languages the definition of sos_step expresses that skip (which is the equivalent of your term) is ignored when executed at the first step of a sequence.  Then, the statement you wish to obtain is a consequence of associativity of sequence with respect to executions as expressed by theorem sos_sequence_aux.
